# Why does warning of 'match can occur not exhaustive' just occur in ADT?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, warnings, matching

In Scala just  `sealed trait` or `sealed abstract class` gets **"match can occur not exhaustive"** warning, I mean when the trait or abstract class *is not sealed*, code doesn't have any warning of that! For example, this code:

```scala
object Main extends App{
  abstract class Notification
  case class Email(sender: String, title: String, body: String) extends Notification
  case class SMS(caller: String, message: String) extends Notification
  case class VoiceRecording(contactName: String, link: String) extends Notification

  object Notification{
    def filterValues(filter: Notification): String = filter match {
      case Email(_,_,_) => "Filter by email"
    }
  }
  val AliceSMS: SMS = SMS("Alice", "Hi Alice")
  filterValues(AliceSMS)
}
```

This code gets error of **matching** in run time, but it doesn't have any warning in compile time.
Do you know why Scala just check the match case exhaustive on ADT??

Comment: Because for non sealed traits is impossible to do an exhaustive check.

Comment: Do you know why? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Because anyone can extend that trait in any place and in any moment, even runtime. So again, that match is always unsafe by definition.

Comment: Run time aside, compiler could know the inheritance of the trait, so it could catch that, why it isn't supported by the compiler?

Comment: Again, it can't. I can extend that in another file, in another module, in another project. - That is the joke of sealed, that is the only reason that exists.